# Update on the fly a ttk.OptionMenu without affecting its previous callback/command

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, optionmenu, tkinter-menu

I am doing a large GUI with different **ttk.OptionMenu** widgets that need to be updated often depending on the interaction with the user. Each time the user selects another value from the menu, there is a function callback by the widget via the command input. The command works fine until I need to update the possible values within the OptionMenu widget. After updating using `add_command`, my previous callback does not work anymore.

Is there any way of updating the possible inputs of a ttk.OptionMenu without affecting its original callback? Let me put a dummy example to illustrate my problem. My original code would be like

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk

        
def printing(variable,*args):
    
    print('ok')
      
    if variable: 
        print(variable)

root=Tk()
List=['Madrid', 'Paris', 'Brussels']
variable = StringVar()

optionmenu = ttk.OptionMenu(root,variable,'', *List,
                            command=printing) 
optionmenu.pack()      
root.mainloop()
```

Then the user would update the list dynamically, and the menu needs to be updated on the fly, using:

```
newList = ['Madrid', 'Paris', 'Brussels', 'London']
menu = optionmenu["menu"]
menu.delete(0, "end")
for string in newlist:
    menu.add_command(label=string,
                      command=lambda value=string: variable.set(value))
```

but doing this operation, the callback `printing` would not work anymore. Also important to mention that one clicked in one option it should become the value showed by the OptionMenu ( so the StringVar variable is settled to that input)

I hope it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an internal class `_setit` in `tkinter` module which is used by `OptionMenu` internally to populate the values.  You can use this class as below:

```py
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk, _setit
...

for value in newList:
    menu.add_command(label=value, command=_setit(variable, value, printing))
```

Comment: I think this is what i need... Just a doubt, in case the function ( in this case pricing) would require some input, it could be introduced here as well?

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I meant printing(), not pricing sorry.... in this case printing does not require any input to work, but in other scenarios, it could require one. It would work by  menu.add_command(label=value, command=_setit(variable, value, printing(input))) ?

Comment: Then use lambda: `command=_setit(variable, value, lambda: printing(input))`.