# Tkinter - Update data in OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created an `OptionMenu` to display a list of usernames.

For example:

```
self.accounts_option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.menu, user_name_list[0],
                                           *user_name_list, command=self.some_func)
```

At some point I want to update/change this list to be longer or shorter (removing or adding from the list).
My question is: How can I achive that?

Comment: This [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262274/update-on-the-fly-a-ttk-optionmenu-without-affecting-its-previous-callback-comma) may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you put
`self.accounts_option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.menu, user_name_list[0], *user_name_list, command=self.some_func)`
inside its own method in whatever class this is, then you should be able to just make it again with a different list by calling the method.

Comment: This line of code runs when the progrem start. There is a function that triggers when I want to add to the OptionMenu, so inside that function I should call again `self.accounts_option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.menu, user_name_list[0], *user_name_list, command=self.some_func)` or its enough to call `self.accounts_option_menu` and some how change to the new list (data)